# Can Mutex semaphores be used by interrupts?

Tags: operating-system

I have an exam in Operation Systems and I'm trying to solve a sample exams.

Here a sample question:

> Can Mutex semaphores be used by tasks? Can they be used by interrupts? In which
>   cases?

It's obvious that a Mutex can be used by a task, but I'm not pretty sure about being used by interrupts.

By logic I would say not, because you can't hold on an interrupts.

What is the answer for that? and why?

Comment: What about in a multi-processing system?

Answer (score 0):

Mutex - no, because interrupt-handlers cannot wait.

Semaphore wait() - no, because interrupt-handlers cannot wait.

Semaphore signal() - yes, because it does not require a wait.  This, (together with an OS interrupt entry point instead of a direct interrupt-return), is a normal way for interrupt-handlers to signal a thread to become ready/running after the handler exit so it can handle the I/O processed during the interrupt.